# React/Redux: adding multiple objects to redux state with lodash mapKeys()

Tags: redux, react-redux, lodash, state

I am mapping over Posts and Comments ( both in a structure of an object containing indexed objects ).

Now - I am successfully adding a single Comment to state like this:

```
    case FETCH_COMMENT_FULFILLED: {
  return {
    ...state,
    fetching: false,
    fetched: true,
    comments: {
       ...state.comments,
       [action.payload.id]: action.payload,
     }
   }
}
```

And I am successfully adding multiple Comments related to a post to state like this:

```
case FETCH_COMMENTS_FULFILLED: {
  return {
    ...state,
    fetching: false,
    fetched: true,
    comments: _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'id')
  };
}
```

But on the main page when I am mapping over multiple Posts and am fetching their respective Comments, naturally the Comments in state are overridden.

I guess I would have to do something along the lines of:

```
case FETCH_COMMENTS_FULFILLED: {
  return {
    ...state,
    fetching: false,
    fetched: true,
            comments: {
       ...state.comments,
       _.mapKeys(action.payload, 'id')
     }
  }
}
```

However this syntactically does not work. There is an 'unexpected Token' error.

Can anyone give me a hint what the correct way would be?

Thanks,
Jan